# PCB manufactoring-There shouldn't be bottom silkscreen selected?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I use `Eagle` to create gerber files .
When i am trying to check my zip gerber, in 4pcb.com i get this message :

```
There shouldn't be a bottom silkscreen selected. If bottom silkscreen is required, adjust the design specifications entered below.
```

Well, our board has printed values in its top and its bottom, and its 2 layers board.
I dont understand why they say that something is wrong with our bottom silkscreen file.

Here is the gerber file job :

```
top copper: top,pads,vias,dimensions.
bottom copper:bottom,pads,vias
bottom silkscreen: bplace,bnames,bvalues,
top silkscreen: tplace,tnames,tvalues,
top solder mask: tstop
bottom solder mask: bstop
drill: drills,holes
```

Maybe i dont understand something basic here, but is this right ? our board is 2 layers board,has components on both side of it, and also values and names on both sides.

What this error message means? is there any tool to check how the board would look like when ready,so i can know its ok ?

thanks!

Comment: It's all already there in the error: If you want bottom silkscreen, adjust the design specifications entered below. I don't know the site, but in your fruit store, if I tell you I want to pay for an apple and then walk up to you holding an apple and a pear, will you let me have the pear for free? No. You need to also indicate you want the pear and pay for it. Change your order for bottom silkscreen.

Comment: yes i know. thanks very much, but to be sure, what does bottom silkscreen means? is it all the printed value on the bottom of the circuit? all the components values printed there ? another thing, is my files creating seems ok ?

Comment: I don't know if your files are okay, I'm not psychic. Silkscreen is a printing method, but in PCBs it is 100% of the time used for the ink layer with text, so yes, that's your component values etc.

Comment: Do you have components mounted on both sides of the PCB? If not, there may be no important info on the bottom silkscreen so you can save money by not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're selecting your specs, make sure you change the default "Silkscreen Sides" from "Top Side" to "Both Sides"

[image]

Otherwise when it sees a gerber file for "Bottom Silkscreen" it'll say "But you told me to only include the Top Silkscreen!" and give you the error you mention.

Answer (score 3):

This likely means that when you specified the board at the 4pcb site, you probably told them "top silkscreen only", or are using a purchasing option that does not allow for a bottom silk screen.  This is usually the default option, and the ONLY option if you are using some low-budget option.  I haven't used the 4pcb service in some time, as I like some others better, but IIRC, the $33 boards could not have a bottom silk screen.

A bottom silk screen (which means you want printing on the bottom layer) is an extra manufacturing step.  Most, if not all, board houses will do it, but you will pay extra for it.  Because it is more expensive, its often not allowed in the rock bottom pricing options, which are automated to the largest extent possible.